# How can I use Gulp and Browserify for my javascript app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, reactjs, gulp

I am finally trying to bring a modern build system to my app, and I'm hoping someone can help. I think I need a few paradigm shifts.

So this is how my app is structured:

```
/src
  /components
    /Base
      /App.jsx
      /Pages.jsx
      /...
    /Page1
      /Page1Component1.jsx
      /Page1Component2.jsx
      /...
    /Page2
      /Page2Component1.jsx
      /Page2Component2.jsx
      /...
    /...
  /libs
    /bootstrap.js
    /jquery.js
    /react.js
    /...
  /scripts
    /index.js
    /utils.js
  /styles
    /main.css
  /html
    /index.html
```

Right now I have gulp set up to do this:

- Make a new folder `/dest` to put everything
- Combine everything in `/scripts`, name it `main.js`, put it in dest
- Combine everything in `/libs`, name it `libs.js`, put it in dest
- Combine everything in `/components`, run it through babel, name it `comps.js`, put it in dest
- Copy the one `/html` file and one `/styles` file into dest

Then here is how the app runs:

- Open `index.html`
- That page requests `main.js`
- `main.js` requests `libs.js` and `comps.js`
- Everything works

But here is the issue I'm running into: **A lot of stuff here relies on other stuff being global.** `index.js` waits for `comps.js` and `libs.js` to load, then calls `ReactDOM.render(<App />...)`, which means both ReactDOM and App need to be global.

Now I'm trying to add something that needs `require()`, and I try to use Browserify for it. But Browserify takes the code that needs the require and wraps it up in a way that, I believe, makes *nothing* global.

I realize that I need to turn my app into actual modules, instead of just a bunch of files that concatenate and call each other. And I know that avoiding global variables will be a good thing in the long run. But I'm having a really hard time figuring out how.

For example, I have >50 React modules. It seems wrong to add `module.exports` to every single one of those, and then import them all to the main file. Further, some of the things in `/lib` are libraries that don't export as modules, they're made to be run in the `<head>` tag, like Google Charts.

So I guess my questions are:

- Where should my module exports be, and how do they fit into my gulp tasks? Do I concatenate then export?
- How do I deal with libraries that aren't modules?
- Is my app really poorly laid out, and I just need to restructure from scratch?

Thanks, and sorry about the rambley question.

Comment: Think about it this way: `App` only needs to `require` components it directly renders. The each of those components only `require`s what each one of them needs. So yes, `module.exports` for every module is correct.

Comment: Oh, that does make some sense! So App would require the components it renders, and each of those require whatever they render, and it kinda cascades like that. And each component just exports itself. Thank you very much, that helps how I'm thinking about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's nothing wrong with your file structure.

Second, the best thing you can do is follow the "one module, one file" rule. That does mean adding `module.exports` or `export default` to every single file. That's just good JavaScript. But it *doesn't* mean importing them all into your main file, which brings us to:

Third, think in modularity. Files should `require` or `import` precisely what they need and nothing they don't. For example, if your `App` uses `Page1` and `Page1` uses `Page1Component1`, then that's how your imports should work:

```
App -> Page1 -> Page1Component1
             -> Page1Component2
    -> Page2 -> Page2Component1
             -> ...
```

This ensure separation of concerns and protects your code from easy-to-trigger errors later on (like those from nested dependency changes). And your build system should generate *one* file (but you can tackle performance later *if needed* with chunking and so forth).

And you're correct that in this kind of structure, using Browserify or Webpack will ensure that nothing is global - and that's a good thing (though I will note that you can tell them explicitly to expose components, which is sometimes necessary for libraries).

And that leaves libraries that you don't control that you can't import. This does not apply to Bootstrap, jQuery, or React, which all have `require`-able modules from NPM. But assuming that you have a library you didn't mention that is not available through NPM, you can still include it globally in your HTML with a `script` tag and tell [Browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-global-shim) or [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html) to expose it for requiring.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I'm starting to understand it now. I take it that a modern build system probably won't have any concatenation in it. One thing I'm running into immediately: Browserify doesn't seem to like JSX. My instinct it to make a `/temp` folder. Gulp first babels everything and puts it in temp, then browserify bundles everything and puts it in `/dest`. Is that "right", like a sensible thing for a modern build to look like?

Comment: Glad it helps! With the right configuration, Browserify or Webpack will do exactly what you want without any temporary directories. You also probably don't need gulp. BTW - if you're having trouble with your Browserify build, you may want to post another question. Perhaps a missing transform?

Comment: Last time I looked at Webpack and my app, I had no idea how to get any of it working. Now though, I think I can probably turn everything into modules and get Webpack working no problem. I'll do that instead of trying to hack my old gulp file into the new format. Thanks again!

Comment: @fnsjdnfksjdb to make Browserify work with jsx, you need to add it to extensions option. So your call should be `var bundler = browserify({
    entries: paths,
    debug: true,
    extensions: ['.jsx'],
    cache: {},
    packageCache: {}
  });`

Comment: @fnsjdnfksjdb the reason for the above is that Node.js, and by extension browserify, only looks for `.js` files when you do `require('SomeFile')`. So by adding the extension it will look for `.jsx` versions of the file as well.

Comment: As a note, the `.jsx` extension is not required to use JSX. By default, `.js` files with JSX in them with be transformed. Some prefer the `.jsx` extension, and some don't. But if you use it, make sure you heed @MatthewHerbst's advice.